# How to calculate time taken to load url in UIWebView in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, timeout, nsurlconnection

Is their any way to find the time taken to load any **url** on `UIWebView`?

Actually my problem is, to show a timeout error if my url takes more than **10 minits to load**.

Actually I used the bit of code to load my first url, but my first loading url redirects to another url which takes too much time to load.

This is the code I used to load my first url.,

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
  NSURLRequest *requestObj=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:10];
  [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

How to find the time taken to load my redirecting url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
  double timeOutTime = 60*10; //10 mins
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
  NSURLRequest *requestObj=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:10];
  [self performSelector:@selector(timeOutMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:timeOutTime];
  [webView loadRequest:requestObj];


- (void)timeOutMethod {
    ///do what ever you want to do
   }
```

In this method you can cancel the above request

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoading:(UIWebView *)webView {
        // This will cancel the previous request.
        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(timeOutMethod) object:nil];
  }
```

Comment: acxtually, where do i put this code. but, this timeout method will call even my webview loads request with success? confused

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 @interface Foo: NSObject <UIWebViewDelegate> {
        NSDate *startDate;
    }

    // etc. In the implementation:
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:10];
    webView.delegate = self;
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    startDate = [[NSDate date] retain];

    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoading:(UIWebView *)webView
    {
        NSTimeInterval loadTimeInSeconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
        // do what you want to it
    }
```

Comment: can you please tell me the flow of this code, and where can i implement the timeout method?

Comment: @neerajPK if you don't understand this code, you should probably not developing for iOS yet. I have provided a working example -- put the first part of the code whenever you load the NSURLRequest into the webview; the second part is already a separate method you should add to your web view's delegate class.

Comment: sorry , am just a beginner, when i used the code  NSTimeInterval loadTimeInSeconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate]; in didFinishLoading , i got EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Comment: @neerajPK if you're a beginner, you better switch off ARC, then see my updated code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can start a timer as soon as you call `[webView loadRequest:requestObj];`.. and stop that timer in the delegate method implementation of – `webViewDidFinishLoad:`  and also the time out interval is in seconds not in minutes....

But I don't think you should be doing this since the time taken will not always be constant as this depends how quickly the server responds which is based on the traffic at particular instance of time...

so it might finish loading in 3 seconds or it may even take 3 minutes.. so my advice is to give a large amount of time out interval but also show a network connectivity indicator.... 
hoping this helps.